# Pygame independent moving images on the screen

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I am new to Python and Pygame. I want to have a screen in pygame with multiple copies of the same images moving around independently. I have tried to write it as a class and then call instances of it inside the `while` loop, but it doesn't work. Could someone show how can i basically do such a thing using a `class`?

Comment: example - many butterflies using class Butterfly: http://pastebin.com/p2KAfsHH . It use pygame.Surface but it can be image.

Comment: thankyou for the example. What does the `(event.pos)` do in your `event_handle` definition? I coudln't find any thing in pygame named `pos`, where does this come from?

Comment: `event` come from `for event` loop. Different events have different fields. Mouse event has `event.pos` - it is mouse position. See all fields on http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html (see list with yellow background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to keep everything simple

Example:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
window_size = (400,400)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(window_size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Image():
    def __init__(self,x,y,xd,yd):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((40,40))
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.x_delta = xd
        self.y_delta = yd
    def update(self):
        if 0 <= self.x + self.x_delta <= 360:
            self.x += self.x_delta
        else:
            self.x_delta *= -1
        if 0 <= self.y + self.y_delta <= 360:
            self.y += self.y_delta
        else:
            self.y_delta *= -1
        screen.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))

list_of_images = []
list_of_images.append(Image(40,80,2,0))
list_of_images.append(Image(160,240,0,-2))

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    for image in list_of_images:
        image.update()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```

Each image can be called individually from the list and moved by simply changing Image.x/y to whatever you want